# Update/Sync value on all WPF usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

With two booleans (bool 1, bool2) I am changing between 4 `screens`/`usercontrols` (over  `IPageViewModel` class). Every `UserControl` is also connected `ViewModelBaseScreens` class. Above this I have one main screen in which lying two booleans with which I can change my screen.

Every of this screen have same boolean which I like to be synchronized between screens. How to update boolean between `usercontrols`? Or how to bind all at the same time (when Property is change)? What is the best solution?

I just like to transfer bool value between screen what user already set up in previous screen.

I am pretty much beginner in WPF (`MVVM`) so please be gentle with me :)

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lajgx.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not clear. please edit and clearly specify your requirements

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided us full context of the problem, but here are the general steps you should take in any MVVM application:

1. Use an MVVM framework. [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) is my favorite.
2. Inherit your ViewModel from `ViewModelBase` (defined in MVVM Light).
3. Define both your `bool` value as public properties and use `RaisePropertyChanged()` to tell the world about the change.
4. Bind all your screens to the same ViewModel object using standard WPF `Binding`.

Now whenever the values of your bool properties change, all your screens will be refreshed automatically.